# How to implement HTML output encoding in Java?

Tags: java, encoding, filter, xss, server-side

I have a web application which has more than 1000's of JSP & HTML files. Now this application is vulnerable to Reflected XSS and we would like to fix this issue by implementing HTML output encoding.

1) Is it possible to implement HTML output encoding from a common java complement in the server side(without any changes to existing JSP files & HTMLs)?

2) If #1 is possible, please explain implementation details with sample code.

This web application is running in apache-tomcat, jdk 1.6 and ecommerce platform (doesn't have any recent tech stack).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. no. You need to escape everything that needs to be escaped, in a meticulous way. 2. not applicable. Note that HTML fiels are completely static. You shouldn't have anything to do with them.

Comment: In order to prevent XSS, I need to encode the URL using HTML entity encoding. So my assumptions were wrong. Thanks!